# OpenMP code far slower than serial - memory or thread overhead bottleneck?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to parallelize (OpenMP) some scientific C++ code where the bulk (>95%) of the CPU time is spent on a calculating a nasty (and unavoidable) O(N^2) interaction for of order N~200 different particles. This calculation is repeated for 1e10 time steps. I have tried various different configurations with OpenMP, each slower than the serial code by some margin (at least order of magnitude) with poor scaling as additional cores are added.

Below is a sketch of the pertinent code, with representative dummy data hierarchy `Tree->Branch->Leaf`. Each `Leaf` object stores its own position and velocities for current and previous three time steps, amongst other things. Each `Branch` then stores a collection of `Leaf` objects and each `Tree` stores a collection of `Branch` objects. This data structure works very well for complex but less CPU-intensive calculations that must also be performed at each time step (that have taken months to perfect).

```
#include <omp.h>

#pragma omp parallel num_threads(16) // also tried 2, 4 etc - little difference - hoping that placing this line here spawns the thread pool at the onset rather than at every step
{
while(i < t){
    #pragma omp master
    {
       /* do other calculations on single core, output etc.  */
       Tree.PreProcessing() 
       /* PreProcessing can drastically change data for certain conditions, but only at 3 or 4 of the 1e10 time steps */
       Tree.Output()
    }
    #pragma omp barrier
    #pragma omp for schedule(static) nowait
    for(int k=0; k < size; k++){
         /* do O(N^2) calc that requires position of all other leaves */
         Tree.CalculateInteraction(Branch[k]) 
    }
    /* return to single core to finish time step */
    #pragma omp master
    {
        /* iterate forwards */
        Tree.PropagatePositions()
        i++
    }
    #pragma omp barrier
}
```

Very briefly, the CPU-hog function does this:

```
void Tree::CalculateInteraction(Leaf* A){
// for all branches B in tree{
       // for all leaves Q in B{
          if(condition between A and Q){skip}
          else{
                // find displacement D of A and Q 
                // find displacement L of A and "A-1"
                // take cross product of the two displacements
                // add the cross-product to the velocity of leaf A 
                for(int j(0); j!=3; j++){
                    A->Vel[j] += constant * (D_cross_L)[j];
                }
```

My question is whether this crippling of performance is due to the openMP thread management overhead dominating, or whether it is a case of a data hierarchy designed with no thought to parallelism?

I should note that each step is timed to be considerably longer in parallel than serial, this isn't some initialisation overhead issue; the two versions have been tested for calculations that take 1 vs 10 hrs and eventually want to be applied to serial calculations that can take 30 hours (for which getting even a 2 times speed up would be very beneficial). Also, it may be worth knowing that I'm using g++ 5.2.0 with `-fopenmp -march=native -m64 -mfpmath=sse -Ofast -funroll-loops`.

I am new to OpenMP so any tips would be greatly appreciated, please let me know if anything should be clarified.

Comment: How precisely is the tree structure organised? are sub-nodes in a contiguous  array or in a linked list (i.e. the parent nodes only has pointer to the first sub-node and each sub-node to her sister)? I'm working a lot with parallel octtrees (for N-body simulations and SPH), but always find excellent scaling. I'm also curious what you need O(N^2) for -- that's usually approximated via tree or FMM in O(NlnN) or O(N), respectively.

Comment: @Walter Leaves are stored in a doubly-linked list to previous and next leaves along the branch (which could be found 'anywhere' in memory). A tree is the standard choice for these specific kind of calculations (vortex filament model of superfluid helium, see for example [this review](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.2753)) but due to time constraints on this project I am looking for a quicker fix to run a single set of long calculations.

Comment: @Walter I'm guessing you use contiguous arrays?  But you know exactly how many subnodes you have.  If you don't know and have to use a list the memory access might really mess up parallel scaling.  I wonder if a per thread allocator would help.

Comment: @emsr, this is true only for the naive programmer. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for providing the link to the original source! I've been able to compile and get some stats on two platforms: a Xeon E5-2670 with icpc 15.0 and g++ 4.9.0; and on a Core i7-4770, with g++ 4.8.4.

On the Xeon, both icpc and g++ produced code that scaled with the number of threads. I ran a shortened (3e-7 second) simulation derived from the run.in file in the distribution:

```
Xeon E5-2670 / icpc 15.0
threads   time   ipc
---------------------
1         17.5   2.17
2         13.0   1.53
4          6.81  1.53
8          3.81  1.52

Xeon E5-2670 / g++ 4.9.0
threads   time   ipc
---------------------
1         13.2   1.75
2          9.38  1.28
4          5.09  1.27
8          3.07  1.25
```

On the Core i7, I did see the ugly scaling behaviour you observed, with g++ 4.8.4:

```
Core i7-4770 / g++ 4.8.4
threads   time   ipc
---------------------
1          8.48  2.41
2         11.5   0.97
4         12.6   0.73
```

The first observation is that there is something platform-specific affecting the scaling.

I had a look in the `point.h` and `velnl.cpp` files, and noticed that you were using `vector<double>` variables to store 3-d vector data, including many temporaries. These will all access the heap, and is a potential source of contention. Intel's openmp implementation uses thread-local heaps to avoid heap contention, and perhaps g++ 4.9 does too, while g++-4.8.4 does not?

I forked the project (`halfflat/vfmcppar` on github) and modified these files to use `std::array<double,3>` for these 3-d vectors; this restores scaling, and also gives much faster run times:

```
Core i7-4770 / g++ 4.8.4
std::array implementation
threads   time   ipc
---------------------
1          1.40  1.54
2          0.84  1.35
4          0.60  1.11
```

I haven't run these tests on a decent-length simulation, so some scaling could well be lost due to set up and i/o overhead.

The take-away point is that any shared resource can frustrate scalability, including the heap.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing, thank you for going to all this effort. My previous runs were on a 4670K and a 4770, but with g++ 5.1.0. I think I still have a license for ipc somewhere... I am away for the week but look forward to testing your changes.

Answer (score 2):

You problem is most likely **false sharing** due to your use of **linked lists** for the nodes. With that memory layout, you not only have the problem of cache misses at almost every time you walk the tree to another node (as mentioned by halfflat).

A more severe problem is that tree nodes accessed and modified from different threads may be actually close in memory. If they share a cache line, this means that *false sharing* (or *cache ping-pong*) causes repeated re-syncing of cache lines shared between different threads.

The solution to both problems is to avoid linked data structures. They are almost always the cause of low efficiency. In your case, the solution is to first build a linked-list tree with minimal data (only those needed to defined the tree) and then to map that to another tree that doesn't use linked lists and may contain more data. This is what I do and the tree traversal is reasonably fast (tree walk can never be really fast, since cache misses are unavoidable even with contiguous sister nodes, since parent-daughter access cannot be contiguous at the same time). A significant speed up (factor>2) can be obtained for the tree building if you add the particles to the new tree in the order of the old tree (this avoids cache misses).

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks. As stated in my comment on halfflat's answer, I see comparatively few cache misses in the parallel case vs the serial code.

Comment: To clarify, are you suggesting that a tree containing only the positions required in the calculation is created/updated at each time step, to then be used by the interaction function? There is still the problem that the calculation for each leaf must skip its own and its single neighbour's positions, so presumably the false sharing issue still arises. I will read some more on false sharing now I have a name for it, thanks for the help.

Comment: So the topology tree has nodes with a)pointer to parent b)pointer to first node of linked list of children c) pointer to node in data tree with the guts?  Q1: Do you worry that pushing data into you data tree might sometimes force a reallocation and invalidation of pointers?  Q2: If you have a solution to that why does the data tree need to be a tree at all?  Can it be a vector?

Comment: Maybe the topology tree stores the vector index not the pointer or an iterator.  Maybe in-order serialization of the data would help the parent daughter contiguous issue.  I would think.  R P0 C00 C01 C02 P1 C10 C11... would gice a higher likelihood that P0 C00 C01 C02 would be on the same line..

Comment: Sounds like I should probably clarify, I think a lot of jargon is being thrown around with different meanings (my `Tree`->`Branch`->`Leaf` in the example code was purely illustrative and not really related to the proper terms; forgive me, I am no compsci).

Comment: I have a data structure called `Tangle` (for real this time) contains a vector of type `Filament`. Each `Filament` then contains a vector of type `Point` and every `Point` object stores its own position etc. The interaction function simply loops over the vector of points and does calculations based on the position of each point.

Comment: In pre-processing, `Point` objects can be added or deleted, or switched between different filaments; initial calculations had to do this a lot, so it made sense to push new points to the end of the vector, then link them to the required neighbours in the filament by way of two pointers stored in each `Point` object. The data is contiguous (unless pre-processing intervenes) in the sense that the elements either side of a `Point` in each `Filament` are its neighbours along the filament.

Comment: @emsr. As I explained, I map to a tree which the data of all nodes contiguous in memory: one `vector` for the index to the parent nodes, another for the index to the first child node, another for the number of child nodes (child nodes being adjacent) etc. I also differentiate between *cell* nodes (corresponding to a cubic box with child nodes) and *leaf* nodes (corresponding to a single object/particle) and have different `vector`s for these. All *leaf* nodes contained within any *cell* nodes are contiguous in memory in the order of a space filling curve for efficient processing of neighbours.

Answer (score 1):

Performance measuring tools (like Linux perf) might give you some information about cache performance or contention; the first step in optimisation is measurement!

That said, my guess is that this is a data layout problem coupled with the implementation of the velocity update: each thread at any given time is trying to load the data associated with (essentially) a random leaf, which is a recipe for cache thrashing. How large is the data associated with a leaf, and are they arranged to be adjacent in memory?

If it is indeed a cache issue (do measure!) then it may well be resolved by tiling the N^2 problem: rather than accumulate the velocity delta contributed by all other leaves, they can be accumulated in batches. Consider splitting the N leaves into K batches for the purpose of this calculation, where each batch of leaf data fits in (say) half your cache. Then iterating over the K^2 pairs (A,B) of batches, perform the interaction steps, that is, compute the contribution of all the leaves in batch B to the leaves in batch A, which should be able to be done in parallel over the leaves in A without thrashing the cache.

Further gains could be made from ensuring that the leaves are arranged in memory batch-wise contiguously.

Comment: Thanks, I actually meant to ask for a suitable profiler as gprof came up short and intel's vtune doesn't support my kernel. The leaves are not necessarily contiguous in memory due to changes enacted during preprocessing. I will be sure to try your first suggestion and then perhaps consider altering preprocessing to ensure a more useful arrangement in memory.

Comment: After tiling the problem to update the velocity just once per leaf, running on four cores, the cache misses reported by `perf` amount to ~0.164% of all cache references with 1.49 instructions squeezed out per cycle. The serial code has nearly 48% of cache references missing (but with 400 times less cache references overall) and manages to crank out 1.83 instructions per cycle, completing the calculation in a quarter of the time.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'm a bit puzzled though by the description of the tiling you implemented: how do you arrange to have only one update per leaf, without iterating over all other leaves and accumulating? On the overall performance front though, has perf identified any other major discrepancies between the serial and parallel versions?

Comment: Forgive me, I misread your original answer. My "tiling" (that wasn't at all tiling) consisted of still iterating over all points and accumulating the velocity into a temporary vector for a given point per core, only updating the velocity at the end of the function; this only improved performance slightly.

Comment: I am puzzled myself; if this is a cache issue then surely perf (and also cache grind) would be reporting many more (than < 1%) cache misses?

Comment: Indeed, it sounds like a different issue is at play. I don't suppose it would be feasible to extract this segment of the code into a small demo that exhibits this behaviour? It'd allow us to poke at the issue directly.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't the time to extract a MWE at the moment (this was really a side project on top of running many calculations on the serial version). I presume it will be down to something fundamentally wrong with the design of the project, so I will  continue fiddling with it myself when I get time. :) 

If you are really interested then charmedxi/vfmcppar on github should give you a bigger picture.

Answer (score 1):

May be unrelated to performance, but the code as it written now has strange parallelization structure.

I doubt it can produce correct results, because the `while` loop inside the `parallel` does not have barriers (`omp master` does not have barrier, `omp for nowait` also does not have barrier).

As a result, (1) threads may start `omp for` loop before the master thread finishes `Tree.PreProcessing()`, some threads actually may execute `omp for` any number of times before the master works on single pre-processing step; (2) master may run `Tree.PropagatePositions()` before other threads finish the `omp for`; (3) different threads may run different time steps; (4) theoretically the master thread may finish all steps of the `while` loop before some thread even enters parallel region, and thus some iterations of the `omp for` loop may be never executed at all.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: You may be right, I assumed that there was an implied barrier at the end of the master block but looking more closely at the documentation it seems that it must be added. Having said that, maybe it is compiler-dependent, as this code produces the correct results (and they would be very drastically wrong if what you are suggesting is happening). Something worth testing, I'll edit my question to remove confusion for anyone stumbling upon this.

Comment: There's little to be gained, I think, from having the `omp parallel` on the outer while loop, instead of simply using `omp parallel for` on the inner loop. (This is what I've used in the fork on github.)